# chrome not respecting box-sizing on inputs

Tags: css, google-chrome

As the title says:  Is there something in the spec that says that box-sizing doesn't apply to inputs? See http://jsfiddle.net/srBAH/1/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you specify a size for the input it will stop jumping. Try putting a height and width and see if it acts the way you want.

Comment: Not really handy. It should work even when there are dynamic widths :p